# script src not loading javascript for angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="dropApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DropBox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainctrl">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>


    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <a id="btn-login" ng-click="login()" ng-model="logbut" ng-show="logbut" class="btn btn-success">Login  </a>
                <div ng-include="template"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="credits text-center">
        <p>
            Amey Totawar
        </p>
    </div>
    <script src="angularsrc.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript File

```
var dropApp = angular.module("dropApp",[]);
var path = require('path');

dropApp.controller("mainctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.logbut = true;
    $scope.login = function() {
        $scope.logbut = false;
        $scope.template = {
            name: 'login.html',
            url: path.join(__dirname,'views','login.html')
        };
    }
});
```

Getting Error:
GET http://localhost:8600/angularsrc.js net::ERR_ABORTED and hence angular module not found.
I tried including min.jquery earlier.
I also tried changing angularsrc.js location, but nothing is working.
Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="dropApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DropBox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angularsrc.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainctrl">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <a id="btn-login" ng-click="login()" ng-model="logbut" ng-show="logbut" class="btn btn-success">Login  </a>
                <div ng-include="template"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="credits text-center">
        <p>
            Amey Totawar
        </p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and your js is same

```
var dropApp = angular.module("dropApp", []);
var path = require('path');

dropApp.controller("mainctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.logbut = true;
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.logbut = false;
        $scope.template = {
            name: 'login.html',
            url: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'login.html')
        };
    }
});
```

This is what you exactly looking for

Comment: If this is part of your previous answer, why not merge them?

Comment: The approach is good...but why can't I include external js file??

Comment: You can include.
let me edit my post the way you were doing.

Comment: Still not working for external js file...works fine for js included in script tag(internal).

Answer (score 1):

Your references should be inside head like

```
<html ng-app="dropApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DropBox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angularsrc.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainctrl">
    {{your code or logic goes here}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to remove ng-app from html tag something like this

<body ng-app="dropApp">
<div ng-controller="mainctrl">
{{your code or logic goes here}}
</div>
    
</body>

Comment: I don't think that ng-app in body tag or html tag would make any difference, still I tried and it did not work out.

Comment: sometime they make difference if we don't reference the way dom reads.
it will be more clear if you put some extra code to understand the problem

Comment: See my comment. your reference error is gone away.
please resolve other points where it break